# How to count the number of times a discord.py bot outputs a message to a text channel

Tags: python, discord.py

```
import os
import discord
from datetime import datetime, time, timedelta
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
from datetime import datetime, time, timedelta
import asyncio

client = discord.Client()

msg = f"<@{some number}>", 'some number that increases every time the message is outputted' ,"days: still waiting for ____ to post -`д´-"


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    msg1.start()

@tasks.loop(hours=24)
async def msg1():
    channel = client.get_channel(some number)
    await channel.send(msg)

my_secret = os.environ['TOKEN']
client.run(my_secret)
```

This code works fine and does what I want, but I want the output message to read "@person 13 days and counting: still waiting for (their name) to post -`д´-

the next day would be 14 etc. How do you implement this? I am currently pulling my hair out trying to code it, but I have no idea how to make a counting function or whatever without getting some kind of error like "name counter is not defined."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not restart the bot inbetween, you can simply count up in the function itself.

```py
number = 1

@tasks.loop(hours=24)
async def msg1():
    global number
    channel = client.get_channel(some number)
    msg = f"<@{some number}>, {number} days: still waiting for ____ to post -`д´"
    await channel.send(msg)
    number += 1
```

If you restart the bot inbetween and want the bot to keep counting up you have to store your number somewhere like a .json file or a database.

Comment: When I use that code I get the error: local variable 'number' defined in enclosing scope on line 26 referenced before assignment

Comment: Did you define the number before the task loop like I've done in the comment?

Comment: yes I copy pasted and put in my values.

Comment: Yes sorry I messed up, you need to define the number globally. I edited my comment and now it should work.